# React Formik with Google Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using formik to create a form and importing a component that allows me to use google autocomplete.

```
const SearchLocationInput = (props) => {
  const [chosenLocation, setChosenLocation] = useState(null);
  const autoCompleteRef = useRef(null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(props.fieldName);
    props.formik.setFieldValue(props.fieldName, value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chosenLocation && dispatch(auth.updateBusinessLocation(chosenLocation));
  }, [chosenLocation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadScript(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY}&libraries=places`,
      () => handleScriptLoad(handleOnChange, setChosenLocation, autoCompleteRef)
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="search-location-input">
      <FloatInput
        ignoreError
        type="text"
        name={props.fieldName}
        ref={autoCompleteRef}
        position={props.position}
        label={props.label}
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Normal typing into the box keeps the text in handleOnChange. Value and fieldname are fine and log as console.

I pass this function to handleScriptLoad, that essentially returns the result of the search. Works fine. Code for that is below.

```
const handlePlaceSelect = async (handleOnChange, setChosenLocation) => {
  const addressObject = autoComplete.getPlace();
  const query = addressObject.formatted_address;
  handleOnChange(query);
  setChosenLocation(addressObject);
};
```

When the handleOnChange runs from that function I get the console log results as expected. I also logged formik values after setting and value is there.

So, the issue: If i find autocomplete result, arrow down and press enter, the form input value updates, all working great. BUT, if i choose to click the result, the form resets.

I think the whole form is re rendering onBlur/Outside click. So does anybody know how to detect and override on particular field?

Comment: Try to complete the value on onlick().Doesn't it work?

Comment: I think i have narrowed it down to a click event on the place results is causing the whole form to re-render as i realise I am also losing values from other parts of the form. So clicking is causing a rerender of whole parent form (arrow and enter works ok as mentioned). The form values set ok, as I checked a console log of values before leaving function. But then re render loses all values

Comment: I have switched to using local state to set value, then onBlur i an updating to form value. The trouble is, selecting the result isnt being seen as an onBlur event. So i have to click in and out again to set formik value.